# aws lambda docker (No such file or directory )

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, docker, aws-lambda

I'm developping a stack using aws but I have a problem with a lambda that use container image.
I tested localy with sam local invoke and it worked. I also did :

docker pull xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.dkr.ecr.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/financepredlambda1239247c883/lambdaputs3newc309b10drepo:lambdaputs3new-c474a3da640f-LambdaPutS3new
docker run -p 9000:8080 xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.dkr.ecr.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/financepredlambda1239247c883/lambdaputs3newc309b10drepo:lambdaputs3new-c474a3da640f-LambdaPutS3new
Inside my docker i can use my library

If someone can help me with that i'll be gratefull

```
{
  "errorMessage": "[Errno 2] No such file or directory",
  "errorType": "FileNotFoundError",
  "requestId": "",
  "stackTrace": [
    "  File \"/usr/local/lib/python3.9/importlib/__init__.py\", line 127, in import_module\n    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)\n",
    "  File \"<frozen importlib._bootstrap>\", line 1030, in _gcd_import\n",
    "  File \"<frozen importlib._bootstrap>\", line 1007, in _find_and_load\n",
    "  File \"<frozen importlib._bootstrap>\", line 986, in _find_and_load_unlocked\n",
    "  File \"<frozen importlib._bootstrap>\", line 680, in _load_unlocked\n",
    "  File \"<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>\", line 850, in exec_module\n",
    "  File \"<frozen importlib._bootstrap>\", line 228, in _call_with_frames_removed\n",
    "  File \"/function/index.py\", line 11, in <module>\n    from openbb_terminal.sdk import openbb\n",
    "  File \"/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/openbb_terminal/sdk.py\", line 29, in <module>\n    import openbb_terminal.core.sdk.sdk_init as lib\n",
    "  File \"/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/openbb_terminal/core/sdk/sdk_init.py\", line 463, in <module>\n    from openbb_terminal.stocks.options import (\n",
    "  File \"/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/openbb_terminal/stocks/options/intrinio_model.py\", line 16, in <module>\n    intrinio.ApiClient().set_api_key(get_current_user().credentials.API_INTRINIO_KEY)\n",
    "  File \"/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/intrinio_sdk/api_client.py\", line 72, in __init__\n    self.pool = ThreadPool()\n",
    "  File \"/usr/local/lib/python3.9/multiprocessing/pool.py\", line 927, in __init__\n    Pool.__init__(self, processes, initializer, initargs)\n",
    "  File \"/usr/local/lib/python3.9/multiprocessing/pool.py\", line 196, in __init__\n    self._change_notifier = self._ctx.SimpleQueue()\n",
    "  File \"/usr/local/lib/python3.9/multiprocessing/context.py\", line 113, in SimpleQueue\n    return SimpleQueue(ctx=self.get_context())\n",
    "  File \"/usr/local/lib/python3.9/multiprocessing/queues.py\", line 341, in __init__\n    self._rlock = ctx.Lock()\n",
    "  File \"/usr/local/lib/python3.9/multiprocessing/context.py\", line 68, in Lock\n    return Lock(ctx=self.get_context())\n",
    "  File \"/usr/local/lib/python3.9/multiprocessing/synchronize.py\", line 162, in __init__\n    SemLock.__init__(self, SEMAPHORE, 1, 1, ctx=ctx)\n",
    "  File \"/usr/local/lib/python3.9/multiprocessing/synchronize.py\", line 57, in __init__\n    sl = self._semlock = _multiprocessing.SemLock(\n"
  ]
}
```

I m trying to develope a stack based on the result of this lambda.